# NERDTree reload new files

Tags: vim, nerdtree

If I add a file to the same directory opened in `NERDTree`, the only way I can see the file added is if I quit vim and start it again .

Is there a way I can reload the files in `NERDTree`?

Answer (score 430, accepted):

You could close and reopen NERDTree or simply hit <kbd>r</kbd> to refresh the current directory's listing or <kbd>R</kbd> to refresh the root directory's listing .

Do you see "Press ? for help" at the top of the NERDTree window? It means that you can press <kbd>?</kbd> for help. If you do, you will see an exhaustive listing of NERDTree shortcuts. That's neat.

More generally, many plugins have a thorough documentation that you can access with `:help <pluginame>`.

Comment: closing and re-opening NERDTree doesn't work ... r works ! Thanks !

Comment: Re-opening it didn't work because NERDTree caches the directory listing. You can see a message to that effect when refreshing with 'r'.

Comment: I'd looked over the `?` help three times and never saw `r`!

Comment: Indeed, the NERDTree help window does not list the `r` shortcut

Comment: The NERDTree `?` quickhelp does list these shortcuts, in its “Filesystem mappings” section. It lists “`r`: refresh cursor dir” and “`R`: refresh current root”.

Comment: Upvoted for `Do you see "Press ? for help"? It means that you can press ? for help.`

Answer (score 24):

As @romainl answered above; press <kbd>r</kbd> to refresh current directory or <kbd>R</kbd> to refresh root directory.

You can consider adding new files from nerdTree itself by pressing <kbd>m</kbd>, then <kbd>a</kbd> to add a new file (or directory by adding a trailing slash). This way you don't need to refresh nerdTree to see the new added file.

Answer (score 11):

### Refresh NERDTree

Instead of hitting <kbd>R</kbd> in the `NERDTree` window, I use a custom map that does it for me:

```
nmap <Leader>r :NERDTreeRefreshRoot
```

I've mapped it to <kbd>Leader</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>, but you can map it to whatever you want.

---

**Explanation:**

- It first switches to the `NERDTree` window
- Then refreshes the Root Node (by simulating the `R` key)
- And finally switches back to the previous window

---

<sup>**Note:** You can add a last step to [refresh CtrlP along with NERDTree](https://superuser.com/a/1137895/214953)</sup>

Comment: You can map to `:NERDTreeRefreshRoot` without focusing tree.

Answer (score 6):

You can hit R button by using **feedkeys** function. Just like this:

```
call feedkeys("R")
```

I have defined a function in my .vimrc file:

```
fun! ToggleNERDTreeWithRefresh()
    :NERDTreeToggle 
    if(exists("b:NERDTreeType") == 1)
        call feedkeys("R")  
    endif   
endf 

nmap <silent> <c-l> :call ToggleNERDTreeWithRefresh()<cr>
```

So, when I type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>, the NERDTree will be toggled and refresh root directory.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I prefer to trigger the refresh **automatically** when **focusing** the NERDTree window. This autocommand (in your `.vimrc`) will do it

`autocmd BufEnter NERD_tree_* | execute 'normal R'`